# Flutter MaterialBasedCupertinoThemeData usage

Tags: flutter

I create a simple MaterialTheme for both light and dark and then try and use MaterialBasedCupertinoThemeData to create a derived CupertinoThemeData from that. What I find however when I switch to dark mode on IOS the system still displays the AppBar background colour in white, the light theme seems to convert correctly. My question is, is there any reliable way to covert a materialtheme to a cupertinotheme or does everything need to be done manually and 4 themes need to be created to in order to support Android and IOS ?

Answer (score 2):

There seems to be a bug related to the bar, not limited to it:

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/51899

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/71590

Based on recommendations from these tickets, you can fix bar and text colors by specifying proper Cupertino overrides like below:

```
final materialDarkTheme = ThemeData.from(
        colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(
            seedColor: Colors.greenAccent, brightness: Brightness.dark))
    .copyWith(
  cupertinoOverrideTheme: const CupertinoThemeData(
      brightness: Brightness.dark,
      textTheme: CupertinoTextThemeData(),
      barBackgroundColor: CupertinoColors.systemBackground),
);

final cupertinoDarkTheme = MaterialBasedCupertinoThemeData(materialTheme: materialDarkTheme);
```